# Is it posible to port Android for a Symbian phone

Tags: android, symbian, port

I have a Symbian based phone with a ARM Cortex-A8 processor (SonyEricsson Vivaz) and was thinking on how hard would it be to try and port the Android OS for it. Obviously Android runs on a myriad of devices with different hardware so I imagine it shouldn't be too hard to adapt it to SE hardware. Could some one give me a clue where to start or if this is even undertakable...

Answer (score 4):

How much information do you have about the hardware in the phone ? Are you starting completely from scratch ?

Porting Android is not simple task. First thing is to have Linux running (preferably 2.6.32 for more compatibility with the latest releases of AOSP.

If you can find a kernel that can run on your phone, that's one big step. After that, you want make sure that the peripherals you want to use also have the right drivers : touch interface, LCD display, SD card, audio, video. The ones that are probably most difficult will be wifi, radio (GSM) and power management module.

If you get that far, you don't have that much to go anymore, a few more changes in the kernel needed for Android, be able to compile Android correctly file system, hook up a few things like buttons and correctly interface with the drivers mentioned above...

But overall, definitely not an easy task (IMHO).

Comment: Porting OS is definitely hard task. Just a note: I think it will be probably easier to port Symbian to other HW then Android:))

Comment: Sorry for my (very) late reply, I have been incredibly busy lately. Your extensive answer gave me a good hint of what was to come if I tried doing this and I decided not to, it is too much work and I have not nearly enough time or the experience for it. Thank you again! I can only hope that this will be helpful is someone else ever tries to do it :)